# latexmk with xelatex and pdfx does not converge

Tags: xetex, latexmk

Given the following minimal example:

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.xmpdata}
\Title{Minimal Example}
\Author{John Doe}
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[a-1b]{pdfx}

\begin{document}
    Test
\end{document}
```

and

```
$pdf_mode = 5;
$xelatex = "xelatex --shell-escape %O %S";
$xdvipdfmx = "xdvipdfmx -z 0 -o %D %O %S";
$dvi_mode = 0;
$postscript_mode = 0;
```

in the `latexmkrc` does not converge when built with `latexmk`. I have also tried

```
$pdf_mode = 1;
$pdflatex = "xelatex --shell-escape --output-driver=\"xdvipdfmx -z 0\" %O %S";
```

in the latexmkrc with the same result.

The `--shell-escape` and `-z 0` are added as required by pdfx. The output file itself appears to be produced correctly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By running `latexmk -diagnostics`, I was able to find out that, apparently, the `pdfx` package causes the creation of a file `creationdate.timestamp` which `latexmk` recognizes as an input file. And it changes on every run.

By adding `$hash_calc_ignore_pattern{'timestamp'} = '^';` to the `latexmkrc` file, you can tell `latexmk` to ignore all lines of `.timestamp` files, thereby working around the issue.